# Setting up In-Built Bluetooth from RaspberryPi3 using image created with Yocto Jethro

Tags: wireless, pi-3, bluetooth, yocto

I've created an image for the RaspberryPi3 with Yocto Jethro (rpi-basic-image) and Ubuntu 14.04. 
I've included bluez5 and bluetooth in the DISTRO_FEATURES variable.

```
        DISTRO_FEATURES_append += " bluez5 bluetooth wifi"
```

In the IMAGE_INSTALL variable I've included  bluez5 and linux-firmware-brcm43430:

```
        IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " linux-firmware-brcm43430 bluez5 i2c-tools python-smbus bridge-utils hostapd dhcp-server iptables wpa-supplicant wiringpi rpio rpi-gpio"
```

My image works. I also can start my wlan.
Now I try with the command *hciconfig* but it does not delivers any device.

```
        root@raspberrypi3:~# hciconfig
        root@raspberrypi3:~#
```

Neither do *hcitool dev*

```
        root@raspberrypi3:~# hcitool dev
        Devices:
        root@raspberrypi3:~#
```

And if I type *bluetoothctl* then I get the command-line *[bluetooth]#*, but my key-board does not respond any more. I've to get it back with "CTRL C".

```
        root@raspberrypi3:~# bluetoothctl
        [bluetooth]#
```

Do you have any idea what I'm missing to get my bluetooth to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by adding this two variables in the configuration file :

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append += " bluez5 bluetooth wifi systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
```

Build your image and start the Bluetooth daemon manually:

```
systemctl start bluetooth
```

Comment: Take note that this 'fix' will migrate the entire boot subsystem to systemd. Beware it might have serious side effects.