# PI Zero W Bluetooth Device not recognised yocto poky

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, yocto

I have built an yocto poky image with bitbake and it doesn't seem to recognise the bluetooth device/controller.

I have seen this [issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49970/setting-up-in-built-bluetooth-from-raspberrypi3-using-image-created-with-yocto-j) and doesn't help.

My local.conf has extra for distro features

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append += " systemd bluez5 bluetooth wifi"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
```

My image file also IMAGE_INSTALL s

```
pi-bluetooth \
bluez5 \
```

I have also made sure the config.txt does not apply the

```
   dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

I can successfully systemctl start bluetooth and it starts running. When I check status its active running.

But if I check hciconfig or bluetoothctl it shows no devices or controller available.

I have also killed rfkill unblock bluetooth

I must be missing something. Any ideas on how to get the device recognised ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being around the mis-configuration of the image resulting with incorrect setup serial port connecting to the bluetooth device.

Roughly,

I has IMAGE_INSTALL as

```
bluez5
udev-rules-rpi
```

I used local.conf as

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""
```

Make sure "sysvinit" is not defined to run elsewhere.

If trying to debug make sure systemctl hciuart serivce is running rather then focusing on systemctl bluetooth service. The hciuart service is required to register the device first.

There was nothing wrong with install of Bluez; so I wouldn't touch that. It should install 5.5 with latest kernel...

Current version used..

LINUX_VERSION = "4.19.69"

RPIFW_DATE = "20190830"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BlueZ is not well documented and drivers don't seem to catch up raspbian version changes.

One thing you might try is to update to BlueZ 5.5

[What is the status of `bluez`, and where is the man page?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96207/what-is-the-status-of-bluez-and-where-is-the-man-page)

.END

Comment: Good thought; but its running Version 5.5 already.

Comment: @zhjh, Ah yes, sorry to forget saying that it is Revision Date: 26 July 2019, with update on Rpi4B 
https://3pl46c46ctx02p7rzdsvsg21-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/1908_Tutorial-How-to-set-up-BlueZ__UpdateLFC_FINAL.pdf.  I suspect the old kernels are problematic.  This update tells how to compile an updated kernel.